# A separate variable for each function call

Tags: python, function, raspberry-pi, global-variables, gpio

I want the start variable to be special every time the function is called
Otherwise, it will only be executed the first time

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

red = 26
green = 19
blue = 13
start = time.monotonic()

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(red, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(green, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(blue, GPIO.OUT)

def led(pin, on, off):
    global start

    if(pin==26):
        color = "Red"
    elif(pin==19):
        color = "Green"
    elif(pin==13):
        color = "Blue"

    if not GPIO.input(pin):
        if now >= start + off:
            GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH) 
            print(color, "ON")
            start = now

    if GPIO.input(pin):
        if now >= start + on:
            GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW) 
            print(color, "OFF")
            start = now
try:
    while True:
        now = time.monotonic()
        led(red, 1, 1)
        led(green, 2, 2)
        led(blue, 3, 3)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.output(red, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(green, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(blue, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

i want red led turn on/off every second
Green led every two seconds
Blue led every three seconds
Simultaneous
But now only the red led is running
because the start variable changed by red led

Comment: Use time.sleep()

Comment: @toyotaSupra  
It causes the whole program to stop

Comment: No!. You do not understand. Follow this link https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28984/how-to-blink-leds-on-off-continually-while-continuing-execution-of-a-script

Comment: This is better tutorial https://avcourt.github.io/tiny-cluster/2019/09/18/pi_led.html

Comment: @toyotaSupra   hi, thank you but time.sleep()  does not have multi-tasking capability, so the program stops until the previous task is completed